# Асинхронные http запросы Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

С некоторого количества сайтов(~20) надо собрать информацию(json ~100 объектов в массиве) и после сбора вывести ее в RecyclerView.

2 варианта:

1. сделать один экземпляр retrofit на все приложение,и синхронно
   обращаться к каждому сайту поочереди, загружая данные например в
   обычную коллекцию.
2. сделать для каждого сайта свой экземпляр и асинхронно собирать
   информацию в потокобезопасную  коллекцию

Нужна\возможна ли тут асинхронность?
Я понимаю что объемы смешные. Но меня больше беспокоит если API сайтов иногда будет давать задержку , даже небольшую 0,2с, то с 20 сайтов может накапать 1-2с. А это уже очень заметно.

Comment: Я бы делал через Rx. Там и синхронность, и сбор результатов...